# python choose list, then from winning list choose a item

Tags: python

trying to do as stated, have python choose one list at random and then choose a statement from within the "winning" list and output it

something like:

```
import random

list1 = a, b, c, d
list2 = e, f, g, h
list3 = i, j, k, l
list4 = list1, list2,list3

output = random.choice(list4)
print(output)

but say list3 won and the output is k
```

Comment: `random.choice(output)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 the code:

```
import random

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
list3 = ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
list4 = [list1, list2, list3]

winning_list = random.choice(list4)
output = random.choice(winning_list)
print(output)
```

Gives me:

> ">>> j

Or some other random letter from the list of lists!
Would this be like what you are trying to do?

Comment: lol thats the one, i feel so dumb for not trying to do one random after another lol

Comment: @TheTripleDeuce Hey it's ok! It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that there's something to give values to `a`, `b`, ..., `l`, and focus on the bit that you are interested in. You are most of the way there - you have already divined that to get a random item from a list `x` you can use `random.choice(x)`. The final step, having chosen a random list, is to choose a random item from it. In code:

```
output = random.choice(random.choice(list4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your lists into another list. Get a random integer between 0 and the length of your list. Subtract 1 because your list begins with 0.

```
from random import randint

list1 = a, b, c, d
list2 = e, f, g, h
list3 = i, j, k, l
list4 = list1, list2,list3
#get random list
list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]
length_of_list = len(list_of_lists)
rand = randint(0, length_of_lists - 1)
randlist = list_of_lists[rand]
#Repeat to get random item
lenlist = len(randlist) #get length of list
rand = randint(0,lenlist -1)
random_item = randlist[rand]

print(random_item)
```

Comment: I like the random.choice answer better.